# Find the maximum area of a triangle

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

> The maximum area of a triangle whose sides $a,b,c$ satisfy $0\le a\le1,1\le b\le2,2\le c\le3$

---

We can clearly see that $1,2,3$ as sides does not make a triangle so we can't just choose the maximum values.

Then I tried using triangle inequalities but in vain.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Also there is an exact same question asked on this site, about $9$ years ago, but no one there gave a correct, satisfactory answer and also the OP did not accept the two so-called answers that were posted there.

[Area of $\triangle ABC$ whose sides $a,b,c$ satisfy $0\leq a \leq1;1\leq b \leq2;2\leq c \leq3$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031053/area-of-triangle-abc-whose-sides-a-b-c-satisfy-0-leq-a-leq11-leq-b-leq2)

Comment: Please add a link to the “exact same question” on this site.

Comment: @MartinR done...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area of $\triangle ABC$ whose sides $a,b,c$ satisfy $0\leq a \leq1;1\leq b \leq2;2\leq c \leq3$ is](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031053/area-of-triangle-abc-whose-sides-a-b-c-satisfy-0-leq-a-leq11-leq-b-leq2)

Comment: The answers to that old question are fine, even if not accepted.

Comment: Both answer in the aforementioned question are saying the same thing: forget the last constraint (on $c$) and maximize the area under only two first. Less constraints will make area only better. Then check if the last constraint is satisfied for the solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar argument: The area will be $(1/2)ab\sin\angle C$ where $a\le1,b\le2\sin\angle C\le1$. We can simultaneously maximize all these factors, and then from the Pythagorean Theorem $c=\sqrt5<3$. So we choose the right triangle with legs $a=1$ and $b=2$.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose we found the optimal value of $b$. Then the area is $\frac 12hb$ where $h$ is the height and clearly $h\le a$. It follows that  $a$ should be perpendicular to $b$ and as long as possible. With this in mind, $b$ should also be maximal, and we end up with the right triangle with sides $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c=\sqrt5$.

Comment: I understand  but shouldn't we consider the constraint on $c$ also, as maybe we can't draw a perpendicular if $2\le c\le3??$...ans why can't we do $1/2 ch$

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad As $2\le \sqrt 5\le 3$, we do respect the constraint on $c$.